# Why does `(var ||= true) = false` throw a syntax error?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I don't get why

```
(var ||= []) << 1
```

works as expected but

```
(var ||= true) = false
```

doesn't.

Could anyone explain why it doesnt work and what is going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a ||= b` behaves like `a || a = b`.

An assignment returns the assigned value, i.e., `var = true` returns `true`.

`var ||= true` will evaluate to the assignment `var = true`, because `var` is undefined at that point. If `var` is defined and its value is `true`, it will return the value of `var`, that is `true`; if it's false, it will return the value of `true`, which is `true`.

`var ||= []` returns `[]`, and your first expression evaluated to `[] << 1`, which is legal.

However, your second expression evaluates to `true = false`, which throws a compile error.

**tl;dr**

`(var ||= []) << 1` ⟺ `(var = []) << 1` ⟺ `[] << 1` ✔

`(var ||= true) = false` ⟺ `(var = true) = false` ⟺ `true = false` ✘

Comment: Thank this guy :) http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: @JúlioSantos Some source that explains it correctly. The rubyinside link that you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you have an object, and you uses its `<<` method.

In the second case you have an assignment, where the right expression must be assigned to a variable on the left, not to an object or expression.